# Bootstrap button dropdown in btn-container with other buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am create a WYSIWYG editor in my free time. I decided I wanted to use the drop down to allow myself to select formatting. The problem is when I add a dropdown it isnt under the button but at the beginning of the the button container.

here is an image to show what I mean.

[image]

The first button looks active because the text is aligned left... Sorry I tried to find a way to fix that but the dropdown is from the last button.

My question is, is there a way to align a Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown, with the button it is supposed to be on or atleast make the dropdown with the width of the button container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can just add a rule, `left: auto; right: 0;` for the `<ul>` coming there, by targeting or giving a class, say `.right-menu`, this way:

```
.right-menu, .dropdown-menu.right-menu {left: auto; right: 0;}
```

A working demo of the same would be in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/r5dMK/).

Comment: but what if the dropdown was in the center or right? I am currently adding "pull-right" class to the list element but would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: No, this is the right way, as `pull-right` will float your dropdown, but won't be affected, as it is absolutely positioned!

Comment: My concern is that this may not always be positioned on the right side. I was curious if there was a way to contain the dropdown so it relative to the button that contains the dropdown and not the actual container for all of the buttons. I think I am going to try wrapping it all in a div or something.

Comment: Thanks, Ill see what I can do with some JS

Comment: You would surely be having one fixed `div` to enclose this right? Now when the condition is surely going to be a fixed one, why do you worry that it might go out of space, although it has many buttons? Don't think too much. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad thing to use `.pull-right` on the `.dropdown-menu` to make it stick to the right of the container.

As seen in [the source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.0/less/dropdowns.less#L63), this class is meant to do that :

```
// Aligns the dropdown menu to right
&.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

---

If you prefer to make it as big as the container, you can try applying this to your menu :

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

You should keep `.pull-right` in case you have bigger menus.

Check the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/npMKx/)